# Dynamic/interactive QGIS webapp

Tags: qgis, buffer, web-mapping, dynamic

Is it possible to use QGIS + plugins to allow users to interact with maps in real time? For example, to allow users to control sliders and change buffer distances in real-time?

It is easy enough to publish all point locations of distinct things, such as  gardens in a state, as well as train stations in a state. But is there any way to give the user access to a slider which draws a buffer radius!circle around all stations and then print a list of all gardens within that radius that fit a given criterion?

I am assuming I need a web database for this, but I am struggling to find any examples or documentation online with someone doing the above.

Would I need to constantly serve up the users requested shapefile? Could I premake them? Really unsure how to go about this.

Comment: Have a look at QGIS cloud: https://qgiscloud.com/ However, I don't think you can implement what you want to do just using that.